# Passing a variable from jQuery within a HTML file to a php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I am trying to pass a variable from jQuery to a PHP file and I am having a difficulty in doing it.

Here is a simple HTML file of "send.html".

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'receive.php',
        data: {
          message : "Hello World!",
        },
        success: function(data) {
          //console.log(data);
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Click here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have a PHP file of "receive.php".

```
<?php
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  echo $message.'<br />';
?>
```

When I click the button on send.html, I get the correct alert saying "Hello World!".
But when I call the receive.php file, I get the following error message saying:

```
Notice: Undefined index: message in receive.php on line 3
```

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by " I call the receive.php file"?

Comment: As you can see it from HTML file, I am not using a form.  When I type the URL of receive.php in my brower (this what I mean as calling receive.php), I want the message variable to be echoed out.

Comment: @user3239379 I just understood what you meant. You see when you make a post request to `receive.php` with the `message` variable. The `receive.php` script gets the message and echos out "hello world" correctly which is why you see the alert box when you open `send.html` in the browser and click on the button. However when you just open `receive.php` in the browser, the php file has no way of knowing the message variable as it is not set when you just "call" receive.php

Comment: If you want `$message` to persist even when you directly call the `receive.php` file. You want to store the string that you send to the php file in something called a [session variable](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp). So you should set up session variable like `$_SESSION['message']=$message`. This variable persists through out the session.The link should get you started in the right direction. Hope it helps.

Comment: You mean this ajax method only works when you submit a form, right?

Comment: The ajax method in your case works only when the button is clicked and only then a `post` request is made to `receive.php` and the corresponding variable is populated and returned which you see in the alert box. I hope it clarified your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['message']` this will work in your `receive.php` only when you go to your php file by clicking the submit button as you have used ajax for calling your php file. But if you will call `receive.php` file without clicking submit button it will give error as nothing is posted on your php file. So for avoiding this error use `isset()` function:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['message'])){
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   echo $message.'<br />';
 } else {
   echo "message not set";
 }
?>
```

For more Details on `isset()` see https://www.php.net/isset

Comment: This means that I need to use a form which will call receive.php when the form will be submitted.  I want to avoid a form since it will call receive.php automatically.  I want a user to call receive.php when he or she is ready.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to caal `recieve.php` directly without form submit then yopu have to usee `isset()` to check the message variable else you will get error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove , at the end of value in data parameter of jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'receive.php',
        data: {message : "Hello World!"},
        success: function(data) {
          //console.log(data);
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The ajax request should be like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "receive.php",
  data: { message: "Hello World"}
 })
.done(function(data) {
  alert(data);
 })
```

Try to use the `done` construct instead of `success` as it is deprecated now. As far as the `receive.php` file is concerned, make sure the path is set correctly in the `url` parameter and best practice should be in the `receive.php` file:

```
<?php
  $message = "NULL";
  if(isset($_POST['message']))
      $message = $_POST['message'];
  echo $message.'<br />'; 
?>
```

This way you won't get a `Undefined index message error` when you run pull up `receive.php` file and would also help you debug it to some extent. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok. So when you run the `send.html`,you are not seeing an alert saying "hello World"?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing the alert with "Hello World!". But when I access to receive.php, $message is still not set.

Comment: Please see my comments below the question, I think I got what you are saying.